# Parallelism structure

Tags: clauses, parallelism

If you were to add up all of the people who have some psychiatric disorder, struggle with depression or suicidal thoughts, have been subjected to neglect or abuse, have dealt with tragedy or the death of a loved one, and have survived serious health issues, accidents, or trauma.

I am not sure if this sentence is correct or not if we consider the parallel structure. Can anyone please tell me if its right or wrong, and why?

Comment: There is no obvious parallel structure here, just a long list. To finish the sentence grammatically, the list should end with "then,  ... ."

Answer (score 2):

You started "if you were to add up ", then described a very broad set of people, and then stated no conclusion to the "if" clause.

You asked about parallelism within the series that describes so many problems. It does lack parallelism, and some of that could be improved by beginning some of the additional elements in the series with "who".

Also, your last conjunction should probably be "or", rather than "and", since you don't mean that all of those people have every one of those problems.

If there were a way to shorten that series, it would be harder to get lost in it.

Comment: ....people who have psychiatric disorders like,

- depression or suicidal tendencies
- trauma of neglect or abuse
- trauma of the death of loved ones, survival from health issues, accidents, etc.